# Gmail sign-in with 2 step verification secure enough for money-generating YouTube channel

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, gmail

My goal is to find out if the sign-in process of a personal Gmail account with 2-step verification turned on, is enough from a security point of view, to serve as the sign-in process for a YouTube channel, which is slowly becoming a source of income. (Subscriber number is less than 3k.)

I have read through a resource of approximately 40 - 50 questions and their subsequent answers and comments on this page, but I believe this very question has not yet been asked or answered in this or another context. Other places online also haven't been fruitful for this question.

Comment: "secure enough" against what? Why is the fact that the channel is generating income a factor?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! With "secure enough" i meant simply if that process is secure enough for a channel which is becoming a source of income. I a sence - should I beef up to something more secure (if that is possible) now that is has started to bring money... I guess I meant if google / gmail "for business" is more secure?

Comment: That does not answer my question. "I want my cup full enough" - full enough to *do* what? To wash a car? Full enough *of what*? In short, what do you want to defend against?

Comment: I guess if it is secure enough against someone deciding to try and hack my account instead of someone with a more secure alternative as the sign-in process.

Comment: A strong, long, random password with 2FA is about as strong of a defence against account hacking as you are going to get. That's the standard advice just about everywhere. Beyond that, it's more about how you use those passwords and 2FA that makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me ask you - do you mean by "..it's more about how you use those passwords and 2FA that makes a difference." if I use that same password and the 2nd factor on other platforms?

Comment: Don't use the same password on any other platforms. This is a basic tenet: never reuse passwords!

Comment: If you're especially concerned about your account's security, you might want to consider Google's Advanced Protection Program: https://landing.google.com/advancedprotection/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "secure enough" 2-Step Verification can help keep bad guys out of your account, even if they have your password.

If you are super concerned about your account,  you may also choose to implement the security key based authentication which can be inserted into your computer’s USB port to authorize logins into your account. This is similar to a code being sent to or generated by your mobile phone, however with physical security keys, you will need to insert it into your device's USB.